Soroban-cli: Invoke functions locally
I am following these tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HsSyOJlKHUQ&t=337s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3in3EvVumiw&t=1530s
regarding writing your first smart-contract and calling its functions.

The similarity with these tutorials is that in both of them, after you build and compile your contract, you can locally call any contract function and see its result, either by deploying the contract or calling the WASM directly, without the need to deploy the contract to any network. When I try to do it using the new soroban-cli version, it requires me to pass the network, the newtork rpc and a source-account.
Why is this happening? Is there still a way to just call a contract function from its wasm without the need to deploy it? I followed exactly this tutorial and in her console it doesn't require it.
bruno@DESKTOP-3JSL9LR:/mnt/c/Users/bruno/my-backup/soroban-hello-world$ soroban contract deploy --wasm target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/hello_world.wasm
error: the following required arguments were not provided:
  --source-account <SOURCE_ACCOUNT>
  --rpc-url <RPC_URL>
  --network-passphrase <NETWORK_PASSPHRASE>
  --network <NETWORK>

Edit: I was asked to be more specific, but I'm not sure what else I can provide or how to be clearer. I was trying to follow this tutorial from the Stellar YouTube Channel, but it doesn't work anymore with the current Soroban CLI. At minute 23:55, she writes in the terminal "soroban contract deploy --wasm" and manages to deploy successfully. However, when I try to do the same, it returns an error requiring me to pass additional parameters such as network, RPC network, etc.
